# The history function preserves recursiveness

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

Starting with an effective coding of the lists of numbers, I recently proved that concatenation of lists is primitive recursive. On the way I used that if a function is primitive recursive, then its history is primitive recursive. Proving the last result, I used the explicit formula for my effective coding.

Given an effective coding, does the history function preserve primitive recursiveness?

By an effective coding, I mean a bijective coding whose decoding functions are primitive recursive.

**EDIT:** Given a coding $k$ and a function $f:\mathbb N^{r+1}\to\mathbb N$, by the history of $f$ I mean $H_f(\overline x,y)=k(<f(\overline x,0),f(\overline x,1),\dots,f(\overline x,y)>)$

**EDIT 2:** Hoping to draw attention to this interesting question I hereby give an example coding, whose history function preserves primitive recursiveness.

Assume $P,L,R$ is a surjective primitive recursive coding triplet for the pairs of numbers. Define $P_k:\mathbb N^{k}\to\mathbb N$ by $$P_1(x_1)=x_1$$ $$P_{k+1}(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1})=P(P_{k}(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k}),x_{k+1})$$

Denote the decoding functions of $P_k$ by $J^k_i\quad i=\overline {0,k-1}$

Define $t:\mathbb N^{*}\setminus\{\varepsilon\}\to\mathbb N$ by $$t(<x_0,\dots,x_m>)=P(m,P_{m+1}(x_0,\dots,x_m))$$

$\varepsilon$ here is the empty list and $t$ is an effective coding of the non-empty lists.

Now if $f$ was primitive recursive and $$F(\overline x,y,z)=P(y+1,P(R(z),f(\overline x,y+1)))$$

then $$H_f(\overline x,0)=t(<f(\overline x,0)>)=P(0,f(\overline x,0))$$
$$H_f(\overline x,y+1)=F(\overline x,y,H_f(\overline x,y))$$

Therefore, $H_f$ is primitive recursive. Conversely $f(\overline x,y)=mem(H_f(\overline x,y),y)$. q.e.d.

Comment: By "the history function of $f$", do you mean the function $g(n) = \langle f(0), \ldots, f(n)\rangle$?

Comment: I will clarify.

Comment: What does this question have to do with computational complexity?!?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if $f$ is primitive recursive, then $H_f$ will likewise be primitive recursive:
$$ \begin{align}
  H_f(\vec x, 0) =& \langle f(\vec x,0) \rangle \\
  H_f(\vec x, y+1) =& H_f(\vec x,y) * \langle f(\vec x,y+1) \rangle 
\end{align}$$
where $\langle\cdots\rangle$ is the function that encodes a singleton list (which must surely be primitive recursive if the encoding is to be "effective"), and $*$ is concatenation of lists (which you've just proved is primitive recursive).

Conversely, if $H_f$ is primitive recursive, then $f$ is too, since it can be recovered simply by composition of $H_f$ with a decoding functions.

---

Likewise $H_f$ is total recursive iff $f$ is. But if $f$ is only partial recursive then the definition of $H_f$ doesn't even seem to be meanigful in general.

Comment: Ah. Yes, sir. But as I said, to prove that concatenation is primitive recursive I used that taking the history preserves primitive recursiveness. If now I use concatenation to prove my result, I'd be arguing in circles.

Comment: @Ivan: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you then. I think you'll have to assume more about your encoding than the _projection_ functions are primitive recursive -- that is, also something about how to _construct_ encodings of lists.

Comment: Would it suffice to assume that the length function was primitive recursive as well?

Comment: @Ivan: No, you need an assumption on a function that _builds_ representations of lists.